# set a time limit to rank discord.py

Tags: discord.py

After several searches I have not found anything that would work out for me. I would like to have users recieve xp every 30 seconds but I don't know how. If said user writes a message they would get xp, but if they write again within the next 30 seconds of the other message they would not receive any xp. This would happen until the 30 seconds are up.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        print("Io sono il bot e non posso livellare :(")
        return
    if message.guild.id not in client.msg_dict:
        #print(message.guild.id)
        client.msg_dict[message.guild.id] = {}
        #print(client.msg_dict[message.guild.id])
    #print(message.author.id, client.msg_dict[message.guild.id])
    if message.author.id in client.msg_dict[message.guild.id]:
        #print("Test2")
        if not (time.time() - client.msg_dict[message.guild.id][message.author.id]) > 30:
            #print("Utente bloccato")
            return  # current time - last msg sent time is not > 30
    xp = generateXP()
    print(f"{message.author.name} ha ricevuto {str(xp)} xp")
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_xp FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    print(len(result))
    if (len(result) == 0):
        print("L'utente non è stato aggiunto al database.")
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES({str(message.author.id)} ,{str(xp)} , 0)")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print("Aggiunta completata")
        await level_up(cursor, xp, message.author, message)
    else:
        newXP = result[0][0] + xp
        print(f"Gli xp di {message.author.name} sono aggiornati a {newXP}")
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET user_xp = {str(newXP)} WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print(f"Aggiornamento degli xs di {message.author.name} completato.")
        await level_up(cursor, newXP, message.author, message)
def generateXP():
    return random.randint(5,10)

async def level_up(cursor, NewXP, user, message):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
    level = cursor.fetchall()
    lvl_start = level[0][0]
    lvl_end = int(NewXP ** (1/4))
    print(str(lvl_start))
    print(str(lvl_end))
    if (str(lvl_start) < str(lvl_end)):
        await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} è salito al livello {lvl_end}")
        print(f"Il livello di {message.author.name} si sta aggiornando al livello {lvl_end}")
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET user_level = {str(lvl_end)} WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print(f"Aggiornamento del livello di {message.author.name} completato.")
    else:
        print("Non è abbastanza!")
        pass
```

EDIT:I absolutely need some answers you can't find anything or the ones you find are obsolete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution using MySQL and the asyncio library.
This is the script I applied according to my needs

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    xp = 5
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT message_id FROM anti_spam WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
    check_message = cursor.fetchall()
    if (len(check_message) == 0):
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO anti_spam VALUES({str(message.id)}, {str(message.author.id)}, 1)")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
    else:
        print("Non puoi livellare!")
        return
    
    #In between create your ranking system, giving user experience etc.
    
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM anti_spam WHERE message_id = {str(message.id)}")
    levelsystem_db.commit()
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a dict that holds user ids that messaged and remove the ids after 30 secs, and check using that in `on_message`

```py
import time

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")
    client.msg_dict = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        print("Io sono il bot e non posso livellare :(")
        return
    if message.guild.id not in client.msg_dict:
        client.msg_dict[message.guild.id] = {}
    if message.author.id in client.msg_dict[message.guild.id]:
        if not (time.time() - client.msg_dict[message.guild.id][message.author.id]) > 30:
            return # current time - last msg sent time is not > 30
    client.msg_dict[message.guild.id][message.author.id] = time.time() # change last msg sent time with current time as the user sent a msg now
    xp = generateXP()
    print(f"{message.author.name} ha ricevuto {str(xp)} xp")
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_xp FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    print(len(result))
    if (len(result) == 0):
        print("L'utente non è stato aggiunto al database.")
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES({str(message.author.id)} ,{str(xp)} , 0)")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print("Aggiunta completata")
        await level_up(cursor, xp, message.author, message)
    else:
        newXP = result[0][0] + xp
        print(f"Gli xp di {message.author.name} sono aggiornati a {newXP}")
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET user_xp = {str(newXP)} WHERE client_id = {str(message.author.id)}")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print(f"Aggiornamento degli xs di {message.author.name} completato.")
        await level_up(cursor, newXP, message.author, message)
```

Comment: I tried. but it has the opposite effect: it blocks you at the beginning and then when 30 seconds pass it doesn't block you anymore and the problem returns.

Comment: tried again and this time does not pass the other two ifs. And I noticed it doesn't add anything to `client.msg_dict[message.guild.id]` what comes out is just `{}`